# Ranorex custom re-run component

Tags: ranorex

Since Ranorex does not provide re-run functionality from under the hood, I have to write my own and before I started, just want to ask for advice from people who've done it or maybe possible existing solution on the market.

Goal is:

- In the end of the run, to re-run failed test cases.

Requirements:

- Amount of recursive iterations should be customized
- If Data binding is used, should include only Iterations for Data binding that failed

Comment: I was wondering why you need to re-run failed test cases since you know that they failed?  Maybe just improving the reliability of your automation so that results are more consistent?  I noticed that when a test case is executed many times, it will fail once in a while but this is usually fixable...

Comment: Yes, usually fails happen once in a while, but now consider frameworks that have +10k test cases, and multiple runs a day and you will have a lot for analyzing. Yes improving of automation is always ongoing task, but rerun is least that you can do to make your life easier till it's reliable enough. Also, sometimes bug in app will affect random areas and after hot fix you want to rerun all failed TC, so having them stored somewhere so you can simply press one button to execute make it very handy.

Comment: Starting with Ranorex 7.2, re-run of failed test case is a new feature. See release notes: https://www.ranorex.com/release-notes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### Possible solutions:

---

1a. **Based on the report xml:** Parse report and collect info about all failed TC.

*Cons: 
     Parse will be tricky*

**or:**

1b. **Or create list of failed TC on runtime :** If failure occurs on tear-down add this iteration to the re-run list (could be file or DB table).

Using for example:

```
string testCaseName = TestCaseNode.Current.Name;
int testCaseIndex = TestSuite.Current.GetTestCase(testCaseName).DataContext.CurrentRowIndex;
```

**then:**

2a. Based on the list, run executable with parameters, looping though each  record.
like this:

```
testSuite.exe /tc:testCaseName tcdr:testCaseIndex
```

**or:**

2b. Or generate new TestSuite file .rxtxt and recompile solution to created updated executable.

**and last part:**

3a. In the end repeat process, checking that `failedTestCases == 0 || currentRerunIterations < expectedRerunIterations` with script through CI run executable

**or:**

3b. Wrap whole Test Suite into Rerun test module and do the same check for  `failedTestCases == 0 || currentRerunIterations < expectedRerunIterations` and run Ranorex from TestModule

---

*Please let me know what you think about it.*

Comment: Here, I described few main options for different components of rerun. You can combine  and choose the one that fits you the best. I personally go with 1b 2a 3a

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Ranorex command line argument possiblities to achieve this. Main thing would be to structure the suit accordingly that each test-case could be run seperately.

During the test I would log down the failed test cases either into a text file, database or any other solution that you can later on read the data from (even parse it from the xml result if you want to).

And from that data you'll just insert the test-case name as a command line argument while running the suite again:

```
testSuite.exe /testcase:TestCaseName
```

or

```
testSuite.exe /tc:TestCaseName
```

The full command line args reference can be found here:
https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/lesson-4-ranorex-test-suite

Comment: Yes, that's one of the options. Do you have examples by chase how I can get info about TestCaseName and Test case iteration.

Comment: You can get the test-case name by the following code:
    String name = TestCase.Current.Name;

For itteration I actually don't know. There might be a Ranorex method but if there isn't one, you could actually just achieve the same with a basic counter implementation.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Martin for help. I'll look for solution for iterations counter and post the answer later.